Allow to edit post in any case
As you know a lot of my posts was removed by bot... For example this Sad story, but I am ok, I want recreate it. But looks like I need to do reverse engineering because I can't just copy text, my text contain a lot of hyperlink and I need put it again in special format.
I ask to allow edit post in any case, even if user has no access to publish what he edit such new functionality helps to copy source of post...

Can you see the "Source" links on the revision history page? https://stackoverflow.com/posts/78336327/revisions

"As you know a lot of my posts was removed by bot" - actually, I don't know. I'd be surprised if anyone here knew that. Please don't throw that phrase around willy-nilly.

"Sad story, but I am ok, I want recreate it." Please don't repost deleted questions. If you want the post to be undeleted, that's fine, you can ask about how to do that, but it was presumably deleted for a reason and you shouldn't try and circumvent that by just reposting the exact same question a second time.

How to get "Source" links on the revision history on first post? https://stackoverflow.com/q/78336312/7915017 @legoscia

Contributions are not removed by a “bot”, the community user isn’t a bot, it more of a script that removes contributions that satisfy requirements to be removed. Those requirements are meet by community users downvoting and voting to close those contributions. We don’t actually know about your past contributions unless you tell us specifically

@SecurityHound OP showed this example (screenshot for the <10k users) - OP's answer was deleted because the question was deleted. And the question was deleted by spam/rude flags.

"I ask to allow edit post in any case, even if user has no access to publish what he edit such new functionality helps to copy source of post..." So are you asking for the ability to edit the spam post in question to make it not spam, and worthy of undeletion?

I wonder why a question with such content has ever be marked as a spam... The question is definitely not complete, but doesn't look as spam at all.

@Tsyvarev given the user account is also nuked, it's probably safe to guess there were more factors.

@ThomA "asking for the ability to edit the spam post in question" - yes. "to make it not spam, and worthy of undeletion" - it is already not a spam! Please open it and check, it is absolutely not a spam! It's the main point why I want recreate post.

You can find the Markdown source by going through the revision history.  Either:

click the "edited Apr 19" link under your post
or if there is no such link, click the "Share" link to get the post id, and then insert it into this URL: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/NNNNNNN/revisions

You can then click the "Source" link for any of the revisions:


That said, the question was deleted for a reason, so think twice before recreating it.

For keyboard shortcut users, you can also get to the revisions by selecting the post (probably J/K/U) -> G (for Go to...) -> R (for Revisions). Works even if the post has no revisions. It's the easiest way I've found to get there.

Can you give me example please for first post in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78336312 I try to use your help but my link looks different with your pattern https://stackoverflow.com/posts/NNNNNNN/revisions

@АндрейТернити replace NNNNNNN with the post ID 78336312, so https://stackoverflow.com/posts/78336312/revisions.

@VLAZ can you open your link? I get "Page not found"...

@АндрейТернити yes, I can, but I have the privilege to see deleted answer. I wasn't sure whether users with <10k rep can see the revision history when they are in your circumstance (answer belongs to the deleted question and the question itself was nuked).

@VLAZ no I can't, my repo <10k. So I want to ask admin of stackoverflow to allow edit post in any case, see my first post. But looks like no one wants to listen me... Can you help to ask admin?
